# Why does $\binom{n}{m}\frac{(n-1)!}{(m-1)!}$ count collections of m ordered lists of n elements?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm reading a book on combinatorial proofs and there is one identity there in proof of which it is written that $\binom{n}{m}\frac{(n-1)!}{(m-1)!}$ counts collections of m ordered lists whose disjoint union is $[n]$. Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joffan's answer is correct, and moreover we can get more feeling on $\binom{n}{m}\frac{(n-1)!}{(m-1)!}$ by the following:

We first choose $m$ numbers which will be the leading elements of the $m$ ordered lists. Let $K$ be the largest one of these $m$ chosen leaders. Consider all $(n-1)!$ permutations of all $n$ numbers with $K$ in the first place, from which we can derive $m$ ordered lists by picking out those segments obtained by cuts before the leaders. In this method, for each combination of $m$ ordered lists, we can find it in $(m-1)!$ ways, hence we actually have our answer: $\binom{n}{m}\frac{(n-1)!}{(m-1)!}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would derive the value as:
$$
\frac{n!}{m!}{n-1 \choose m-1}
$$
but they are the same value:
$$
\frac{n!}{m!}{n-1 \choose m-1} = \frac{n!(n-1)!}{m!(m-1)!(n-m)!} =\frac{(n-1)!}{(m-1)!}{n \choose m} 
$$

The first expression is derived by ordering the $n$ items [$n!$], splitting into $m$ lists by choosing the $m-1$ list divider positions [${n-1 \choose m-1}$], then disregarding the ordering of the lists themselves [$\frac{1}{m!}$].